# VS Code & PHP: No Autocomplete for variables from included files?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have just jumped on the Visual Studio Code bandwagon, but have hit my first deal-breaker: I can't get it to autocomplete variables that I've set inside of an included "config.php" file, where I would set variables like:

```
$some_var = 'something';
```

Then in another file I would include:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

// etc.......
```

Then, in this file I should be able to start typing `$som` and hit TAB or ENTER and `$some_var` would be completed (possibly need to type more letters or select what I actually want if others matched the first few characters...)

With all this editor can do I'm BLOWN away this isn't something that works right out of the box!?  really makes me wonder if maybe I am missing something...obviously it prevents errors/typos...not to mention the time saved just typing.

Anyways, here's what I've done:

On the welcome screen there's common options for "what I do" I used the php and javascript options; no keybindings

I then started to install several other extensions that looked promising from youtubers, and at some point noticed this issue...

I uninstalled ALL extensions and just picked the PHP option, no dice.

So then I started adding several "PHP ________" extensions, including; IntelliSense, Intelephense, Autocomplete, etc... ONE-BY-ONE and uninstalling if it didn't work, just in case there was a conflict - still no luck (obviously).

What am I missing guys!?  I have not seen anyone else asking about this...I hope I'm just over-complicating it and there's something simple I've overlooked...

THANKS.

---

For what it's worth:

If I open the test file in a browser and echo the included variables, they're there.

I'm running Mint xfce, with LAMP:

```
php -v
PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2019 14:54:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

My settings.json has a couple custom things I've added/tried along the way:

```
// PHP TROUBLESHOOTINGS:
//"files.associations": {"*.php": "html"},
"files.autoGuessEncoding": true,
"files.defaultLanguage": "php",
"php.suggest.basic": true,

"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
},
```

Comment: Is this even a feature? I know it picks up functions but unsure about variables.

Comment: It does work with PHP Intellisense - Crane on my visual code. However on first install it doens't always work instantly. I guess this is an index problem..

Comment: Thanks, funny enough PHP Intellisense - Crane is the last one I installed, and is still installed...I just closed out and restarted, nope.

As for if it's a feature - I can't imagine it isn't at least an extension...I've been using Dreamweaver for over a decade and it does it.  I also have Geany installed, and even it does it.

Definitely a feature I think is a must have.

Comment: @TheFirstMinute: It's not a feature of Visual Studio Code. It has some basic autocomplete for the built-in php functions and linting support, but that's it. For everything else you need third party extensions (free or paid, up to you). PHP isn't a microsoft product, so if you want advanced features you need to rely on third party extensions (preferably provided by the language maintainers, i.e. PHP community/Zend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I've been poking around at this off and on for a while...

I've found one extension "PHP Tools for VS Code, by DEVSENSE" it somehow makes this functionality work...however it is a paid extension $179 setup, and $98/year after that (for individuals it's $79, then $49 renew).

**BUT, that tells me it *is possible* with VS Code...**

I've been using Dreamweaver for over a decade, and got used to this functionality - but I've moved to Linux, which Adobe doesn't play nice with...and besides, I hate the idea of recurring billing for software I buy - if they make something new and amazing, I'll buy it...but in my estimation DW hasn't had any innovation for a few years; so I'm happy to fire Adobe (and found VS Code - which is pretty awesome).

Anyways, I guess what irks me; my basic text editor "Xed" (that comes installed with XFCE) has this ability, along with Vi (and derivatives), Geany and Bluefish...and obviously phpstorm and the like...probably a ton of others I haven't tried.

Bottom line; really seems like basic functionality that should work out of the box...and with all the other truly INSANE capabilities of VS Code, I'm shocked there isn't a simple way to make it happen (extension or otherwise); I hope the right person sees this and does something about it ;)

I don't want to seem ungrateful here, this VS Code initiative and the community around it is really amazing - and I am going to continue using it, at least for the intermediate term...

My "band-aid fix":  I have just created a few user snippets based on my dozen or so most common variables that I would have in a config file eg:

```
"$username": {
    "prefix": "$usr",
    "body": [
        "\\$username"
    ],
    "description": "inserts the PHP $username variable"
}
```

Thanks for your interest...and putting up with my rant - if you have any other ideas, feel free.

P.S. I do see on Intellisense - Crane they have a note on release v0.3.7 it says "Fix issue with including file on Linux"...but, apparently not? ;)  I'm not even 100% sure that fix is solving my issue, but it's interesting to see.